# Hexo can not load style sheet

Tags: css, hexo

I just deployed a new blog using Hexo and it is failing when it tries to load the style sheet. The generated declaration in the index.html file looks like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

I can solve the issue editing this file manually as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

Note how the `/` is removed. Is this a bug that hexo has or is this happening just to me. Here is my repo for reference:
https://github.com/enriquezrene/quarkus

develop branch has the code
master branch has the deployed website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda solved the issue forcing to load the css file editing the `head.ejs` file as follows:

```
...
<% if (config.highlight.enable){ %>
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <----- code added ----->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <----- code added ----->

  <% } %>
  <%- css('css/style') %>
</head>
```

However, this does not solve the issue completely since the generated index.html file now looks like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

So it will try to load the other file as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the option on this file ***_config.yml***

```
url: https://enriquezrene.github.io/quarkus
root: /quarkus/
```